# What is an appropriate way to insert structured data from an on-line source into a Tex/LaTeX document? From within, or externally?

Tags: external-files, automation, source

Let's say there is a structured list of items on some on-line source. For example, the website https://nothing.better.to.do-a.shame might contain the following data:

> A blueberry
>
> - `<tag>`Piano`</tag>`
>
> Blue berry
>
> - `<tag>`Bulldozer`</tag>`
>
> Cis-industrial copernican evolution
>
> - `<tag>`Aspiration`</tag>`

Let's imagine the list is long and, for our Tex document, we will want the data between `<tag>` and `</tag>` to be pulled automatically into our document so we can use them.

My question is the following:

Is it better

- to do this outside of Tex/LaTeX, using whatever language you'd prefer, and then create an external (**but now off-line**) file containing the structured data, which one will import into Tex?
- or is it possible and advisable to do this from within Tex/LaTeX, i.e. directly extract the data from the **on-line source** (and thereby thus update the data if necessary) each time on compiling your Tex/LaTeX document?

Comment: I will try a pandoc conversion to `off-line-file.tex` without the `-s` option   and then use `\input{off-line-file}` in the main document.

Comment: TeX [doesn't play with the Internet](https://sdh33b.blogspot.com.au/2008/07/icfp-contest-2008.html). Use a different program to pull data from the website.